# youtube api 3.0 getting the info for a single video

Tags: php, video, youtube-api

I'm trying to get the data for a single video with the Youtube api 3.0 in and I can't figure out how to do it.

I manage to make this example work pretty easily: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php

and customize it a bit.

But now I'm trying to get the info for a single video with a specific Id.

Here what I try

```
$data = $youtube->videos->list("snippet");
```

and this always give me this error

> Cannot unset string offsets in {SERVER_PATH}/Google_ServiceResource.php on line 95

If anyone can help I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 11):

can't give you the exact php code but the url is something like this

```
String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id="+videoID+"&key=" + YOUR KEY HERE + "&fields=items(id,snippet(channelId,title,categoryId),statistics)&part=snippet,statistics";
```

you get a JSON object that you parse :)

Comment: how can I get a owner of video

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've figured it out yet - since it has been awhile, but i believe you are calling a non-existing function. I think it should be:

```
$data = $youtube->videos->listVideos("snippet");
```

Comment: just abit extra that helped me: $getSnippet = $youtube->videos->listVideos("snippet", array('id' => $youTubeId));

Answer (score 0):

Using AngularJS

```
app.controller('oneVideoCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, $location){

$scope.videos = [];
$scope.youtubeParams = {
    key: 'YOUR-API-KEY-HERE',
    type: 'video',
    kind: 'youtube#video',
    maxResults: '1',
    part: 'id,snippet',
    order: 'viewCount',
    channelId: 'YOUR-CHANNEL-ID-HERE',
    playlistId: 'YOUR-PLAYLIST-ID-HERE',
}

// Get single specific YouTube video
$http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEO-ID-HERE', {params:$scope.youtubeParams}).success(function(response){
    angular.forEach(response.items, function(child){
        console.log (child);
        $scope.videos.push(child);
    });
  });
});
```